# How to add a static image to a uipagecontroller that doesn't move with the pages?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I'm using a xib to represent the different pages but need a transparent texture layer to remain static on top of the moving background when a user switches pages.  Is there a way to do it?

This is what I currently use to load the background layer:

```
let imageView : UIImageView = (vc.view.viewWithTag(1) as? UIImageView)!
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: backgroundImage, in: Bundle(for: type(of: self)), compatibleWith: nil)
```

its in a bigger function where load ll the other UI elements for the view.

Comment: Sure - just add it as a subview over-laying the page controller's view, and disable user interaction on it.

Comment: How can you add it as a subview?

Comment: Do you have your page view controller working so far? If so, are you adding it as a child view controller and subview?

Comment: It is working and I'm using viewWithTag to add the xib to it. But it looks like I everything in the xib has to move with the page movement except for the texture layer that needs to be static.

Comment: Edit your question to show the `viewDidLoad` function in your UIPageViewController class. **NOT** the individual "pages" class.

Comment: This is what I have now to load the layer, it shows on screen but moves when the page moves:    let imageView : UIImageView = (vc.view.viewWithTag(1) as? UIImageView)!
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: backgroundImage, in: Bundle(for: type(of: self)), compatibleWith: nil)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150740/discussion-between-donmag-and-swiftyjd).